# Error in magento Admin in customer tab?

Tags: magento, eaccelerator

I have to update Magento version 1.7 to 1.9. I have an error when I update the customer password in Magento admin. It's generate an error

> Fatal error: Invalid opcode 153/1/8. in /home/alisonan/public_html/lib/Pelago/Emogrifier.php on line 495

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is fixed when I add the following code in `.htaccess`:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
php_flag eaccelerator.enable 0
php_flag eaccelerator.optimizer 0
```

eAccelerator is deactivacted with this code.

Comment: Had the same problem
Thanks for the solution